# Obtener los valores de una fila de una tabla dando click en un boton de esta fila

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando obtener los valores de una fila dando clic en un boton que esta en esta misma pero estoy teniendo problemas.

Cuando yo busco por Folio, busco informacion en una BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando obtengo la informacion de la BD la inserto en el body de una tabla y queda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi html

```
<!-- Form --><form id="formInputs">
                    <!-- Card --><div class="card rounded boxShadow">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <!-- Tittle --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <p class="fs-1 fw-bolder"> Edit Work order </p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Folio --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="Folio" class="form-label">Enter Folio Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Folio">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Name / No. Clock --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="requestor" class="form-label">Requisitioner's name / Nombre del requisitor</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="requestor">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="number_clock" class="form-label">Clock number / Numero de reloj</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="number_clock">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Type Fixture --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <label class="form-label">Choose type of fixture / Elige un tipo de fixtura</label>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="type-fixture" id="New" value="New" autocomplete="off">
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="New">New / Nueva</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="type-fixture" id="Prototype" value="Prototype" autocomplete="off">
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="Prototype">Prototype / Prototipo</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="type-fixture" id="Repair" value="Repair" autocomplete="off">
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-warning" for="Repair">Repair / Reparación</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="type-fixture" id="Rework" value="Rework" autocomplete="off">
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="Rework">Rework / Retrabajo</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="type-fixture" id="Others" value="Others" autocomplete="off">
                                        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="Others">Others / Otros</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Name Fixture / PN --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Fixture-name" class="form-label">Fixture name / Nombre de la fixtura</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Fixture-name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Part-Number" class="form-label">Part Number / No. de parte</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Part-Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Building / Department --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Building" class="form-label">Building / Edificio</label>
                                        <select class="form-select text-center" id="Building">
                                            <option value="Building A">Building A</option>
                                            <option value="Building B">Building B</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Department" class="form-label">Department / Departamento</label>
                                        <select class="form-select text-center" id="Department">
                                            <option value="A">A</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Customer / Model / QTY --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Customer" class="form-label">Customer / Cliente</label>
                                        <select class="form-select text-center" id="Customer">
                                            <option value="A">A</option>
                                            <option value="B">B</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Model" class="form-label">Model / Modelo</label>
                                        <select class="form-select text-center" id="Model">
                                            <option value="A">A</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Quantity-assemblies" class="form-label">Quantity of assemblies / Cantidad de ensambles</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" id="Quantity-assemblies">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Priority / ESD Required --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="" class="form-label">Priority / Prioridad</label>
                                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="Priority" id="Low" value="Low" autocomplete="off">
                                                <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="Low">Low / Baja</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="Priority" id="Medium" value="Medium" autocomplete="off">
                                                <label class="btn btn-outline-warning" for="Medium">Medium / Mediana</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="Priority" id="High" value="High" autocomplete="off">
                                                <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="High">High / Alta</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="" class="form-label">ESD material required / Requiere material ESD</label>
                                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="ESD-material" id="Yes" value="Yes" autocomplete="off">
                                                <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="Yes">Yes / Si</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="ESD-material" id="No" value="No" autocomplete="off">
                                                <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="No">No</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Comments --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Comments" class="form-label">Comments / Comentarios</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="Comments" rows="3"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Table --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <table class="table table-sm text-center">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">Files</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="TableFiles">
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Files --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Attach-Documents" class="form-label">Attach Documents / Anexar Documentos</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="Attach-Documents" multiple>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Submit --><div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto mt-5 mb-5">
                                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                                    Send Request
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-send-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                        <path d="M15.964.686a.5.5 0 0 0-.65-.65L.767 5.855a.75.75 0 0 0-.124 1.329l4.995 3.178 1.531 2.406a.5.5 0 0 0 .844-.536L6.637 10.07l7.494-7.494-1.895 4.738a.5.5 0 1 0 .928.372l2.8-7Zm-2.54 1.183L5.93 9.363 1.591 6.602l11.833-4.733Z"/>
                                        <path d="M16 12.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 1-7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 7 0Zm-3.5-2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1h-1a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h1v1a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-1h1a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-1v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5Z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

let tableData = document.querySelector('#TableFiles')
const inputFolio = document.getElementById('Folio')

/* Event Change Folio */inputFolio.addEventListener('change', e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Folio', document.getElementById('Folio').value)

    fetch('./scripts/php/StatusWorkOrder.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    })
    .then(respuesta => respuesta.text())
    .then(json => {
        const jsonDecode = JSON.parse(json)
        if ( jsonDecode.Message == 'Empty' ) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Text empty!',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2000,
                timerProgressBar: true
            })
        } else if ( jsonDecode.Message == 'Not Found' ) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Folio Not Found',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2000,
                timerProgressBar: true
            })
        } else {
            document.getElementById('requestor').value = jsonDecode.REQUESTOR
            document.getElementById('number_clock').value = jsonDecode.CLOCK_NUMBER
            document.querySelector('#' + jsonDecode.FIXTURE_TYPE).checked = true;
            document.getElementById('Fixture-name').value = jsonDecode.FIXTURE_NAME
            document.getElementById('Part-Number').value = jsonDecode.PART_NUMBER
            document.getElementById('Building').value = jsonDecode.BUILDING
            document.getElementById('Department').value = jsonDecode.DEPARTMENT
            document.getElementById('Customer').value = jsonDecode.CUSTOMER
            document.getElementById('Model').value = jsonDecode.MODEL
            document.getElementById('Quantity-assemblies').value = jsonDecode.ASSEMBLIES_QTY
            document.querySelector('#' + jsonDecode.PRIORITY).checked = true;
            document.querySelector('#' + jsonDecode.ESD_MATERIAL).checked = true;
            document.getElementById('Comments').value = jsonDecode.COMMENTS

            fetch('./scripts/php/QueryFilesToWorkOrders.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            })
            .then(respuesta => respuesta.text())
            .then(json => {
                const jsonDecode = JSON.parse(json)
                let node = document.getElementById("TableFiles");
                while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
                }
                jsonDecode.forEach( (json) => {
                    const addRowTable = tableData.insertRow(-1)
                    addRowTable.innerHTML = `
                        <td>
                            <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="${ json.CARPET_NAME + json.FOLIO + '/' + json.NAME_FILE }" target="_blank">${ json.NAME_FILE }</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="deletes">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-file-earmark-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M6.854 7.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708L7.293 9l-1.147 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708L8 9.707l1.146 1.147a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L8.707 9l1.147-1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8 8.293 6.854 7.146z"/>
                                    <path d="M14 14V4.5L9.5 0H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2-2zM9.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 4.5h2V14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h5.5v2z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    `
                    tableData = document.querySelector('#TableFiles')
                })
            })
        }
    })
})

/* Event Change Table */tableData.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.name && e.target.name == 'deletes') {
        let value = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("td").item(0)
        console.log(value)
    }
})
```

Cuando pego el texto en el input con el event onchange llamo un fetch para traer contenido de una BD lo guardo en la tabla con este codigo

```
const tableData = document.querySelector('#TableFiles')

const addRowTable = tableData.insertRow(-1)
addRowTable.innerHTML = '
      <td>
          <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="${ json.CARPET_NAME + json.FOLIO + '/' + json.NAME_FILE }" target="_blank">${ json.NAME_FILE }</a>
      </td>
      <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="deletes[]">
               Click
          </button>
       </td>
'
```

Entonces ya que el boton no se crea al inicio de la pagina, hago esto cuando se de click en la tabla y el nombre del target sea el del boton trato de traer la info de la fila pero no obtengo nada mas que undefined; Y no se de que otra forma traerme esa info.

```
/* Event Change Table */tableData.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.name && e.target.name == 'deletes[]') {
        let value = e.target.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("td")
        console.log(value)
    }
})
```

No se si alguien pueda ayudarme o decirme si estoy haciendo algo mal. Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Prueba de quitar el `[]` del `deletes` en el condicional y dime si ha funcionado

Comment: Ya lo hice, y no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu comentario lo que ahora me parece que quieres es esto:

```
let value = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("td").item(0)
```

Es decir, desde el boton subimos al primer padre (`parentElement`), que es su propia columna, luego al segundo (`parentElement` de nuevo), que deberia ser su fila `<tr>`, y desde alli buscamos todas las columnas (`getElementsByTagName("td")`), de las cuales solo queremos sacar el contenido de la primera de ellas (`item(0)`).

Y eso nos devolverá el elemento contenido en la primera columna de cada fila (en este caso `<a>`). Del cual, por ejemplo, vamos a extraer su contenido con `innerText` en el snippet que pongo a continuación:

```js
const tableData = document.querySelector('#TableFiles')

const addRowTable = tableData.insertRow(-1)


addRowTable.innerHTML = `
     <td>
          <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="otro" target="_blank">Desde javascript</a>
      </td>
      <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="deletes[]">
               Click
          </button>
       </td>
`
/* Event Change Table */
tableData.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.name && e.target.name == 'deletes[]') {
        let value = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("td").item(0)
        console.log(value.innerText)
    }
})
```

```html
<!-- Folio --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
     <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="Folio" class="form-label">Enter Folio Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="Folio">
     </div>
</div>

<!-- Table --><div class="row align-items-center mt-5 mb-5">
      <table class="table table-sm text-center">
             <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th scope="col">Files</th>
                       <th scope="col">Action</th>
                   </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody id="TableFiles">
<td>
          <a class="text-decoration-none text-dark" href="test" target="_blank">file name</a>
      </td>
      <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="deletes[]">
               Click
          </button>
       </td>             
             </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah , así lo tengo nada más que aquí lo cambie porque me reconocía los apostrofes como para escribir código , pero así está en el código

Comment: Vale, disculpa, arreglado. Acabo de editar mi respuesta, tan solo recarga esta página y prueba a ver si asi te convence.

Comment: Aqui si funciona ya que se genera al principio un a y un boton, en mi codigo hasta que el input activa un evento onchange genero ese a y el boton, y no me imprime nada solamente esto `HTMLCollection[]`

Comment: @VictorGarcia Modifica tu pregunta para reproducir ese comportamiento y error. Yo lo he intentado de diversas formas y siempre me funciona, pero claro, segun parece no tengo tu código y quizás tu no activas el `tableData.addEventListener` hasta que sucede algo, la verdad, a ciegas no es facil ayudar, y podrian ser otras cosas.  Haz eso o mira si puedes sacar el `tableData.addEventListener` de cualquier función donde lo tengas para que actue de forma [delegada](https://www.paradigmadigital.com/dev/entendiendo-delegacion-eventos-javascript/) y así solucionar tu problema.

Comment: ya he editado la pregunta con todo el codigo html y las funciones de javascript, el evento `tableData.addEventListener` si lo tengo aparte.

Comment: Por que lo vuelves a definir en el fetch?  `tableData = document.querySelector('#TableFiles')`... si acaso en vez de `let` usa `var` al principio del javascript para hacerlo global, pero definirlo dos veces no creo que sea bueno si ya estaba a la escucha

Comment: Y por si acaso yo usaría getElementById en lugar del querySelector, pues su id es único y lo tiene definido... pueba con esos dos cambios y me cuentas (seguramente no arreglará nada, pero estará mejor puesto creo yo)

Comment: Ya lo hice , cambie por `var` y modifique a `getElementById` y ahora si obtengo pero funciona muy random, a veces si obtengo el dato y otras veces no, de 10 clicks nada uno funciona

Comment: `tableData = document.querySelector('#TableFiles')` y esto lo hacia para actualizar la variable que contiene tableData y asi poder obtener nuevas filas que se agregaran.  De esta forma si me funcionaba en otras apps que he hecho pero aqui no se porque no

Comment: No entiendo que debas actualizar esa variable, pues teoricamente ya la tienes definida al principio de todo, y además ese elemento con ese id no lo cambias en ningun momento, tan solo lo que contiene, por lo tanto deberia seguir funcionando hagas lo que hagas dentro. Al reasignar esa variable de nuevo después quizás estás provocando ese error random que dices. Prueba dejándolo solo con el primer `var` y comenta o elimina el segundo despues del `innerHTML` y nos dices si el problema persiste o hay algun cambio en el comportamiento.

Comment: El caso es que me parece que tu `addEventListener` actua solo sobre la primera definición de la variable durante la carga, y después, al volver a asignarla, aunque sea sobre el mismo selector, se pierde el `addEventListener` y por eso deja de funcionar.  En la delegación de eventos en javascript no hace falta actualizar el padre si los hijos cambian, es más, tal como lo estás haciendo ya ves que no funciona.

Comment: Ya solucione el problema, no era el evento `Listener` o todo lo que se platico, simplemente el boton dentro yo contenia un svg para darle diseño, eso provocaba que al llamar el `e.target.parent.parent.ByTagname('td')` a veces trajera todo el `td` completo o la etiqueta button, al remover el svg porque se me ocurrio como lo ultimo, siempre arrojaba la etiqueta td, MasterGuru te agradezco muchisimo por estar contestando mis dudas! Gracias por seguir contestando jajaja

Comment: Bueno, me alegro que lo tengas solucionado. No acabo de ver si mi respuesta fue correcta en este caso (no veo el svg en tu ejemplo dentro del innerHTML) o al usar el svg en tu caso real deberiamos agregar un `parentElement` más (o dos) para que tambien funcionara.  Si la respuesta fue correcta deberias marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente para siempre. Mira [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a marcar como aceptada la respuesta (si es que lo fue, ahora no lo tengo tan claro).